# How to change the gnome backgrounds default search directory?

Tags: debian, gnome3, gnome-shell, wallpaper, dconf

I'm using

- **Debian10.10** and
- **gnome 3.30.2**

When I change the background from settings as shown below, the gnome checks for wallpapers in the `/home/prithvi/Pictures/` but, I want gnome to check for wallpapers in `/home/prithvi/Pictures/Wallp`, in a custom directory I like.

[image]

Do I have to use `dconf editor` and if so, what value do I have to update so that when I change my **gnome background**, gnome should look up for wallpapers in the **custom directory I've set.** ?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get:

Create a symlink of `~/.local/share/backgrounds`, place it under your desired directory and rename it as you want. Put you images there.